# IntelliJ: How to make unit tests run in separate classloaders?

Tags: maven, junit, intellij-idea

I have imported a Maven project into IntelliJ 12.1.4.

One of the tests gives each object an id and when run from the command line (or in Eclipse or Netbeans) the unit tests all have the id starting at zero.  From within IntelliJ the ids increase without being reset to zero causing my tests to fail.

```
public class CORE_C {
    static AtomicLong globalCounter = new AtomicLong();

    final long counter;

    public CORE_C() {
        counter = globalCounter.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that JUnit invokes each test in its own classloader causing the behaviour I see outside IntelliJ.  Is this a bug, or just an option I have not yet set correctly?  If the latter, what is the proper fix?